# Execution of multiple batch files in different cmd prompts using a single batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 3 batch files, `one.bat`, `two.bat` and `three.bat`. All three bat files have to start in their own command prompt shells. So now I'm planning a `collect.bat` which executes all three batch files in one batch file. But I cant figure out how we can make each of the batch files(`one.bat`, `two.bat` and `three.bat`) run in a different window using `collect.bat`. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `START` for that. Each batch will be STARTed separately without waiting for it to finish

```
start one.bat
start two.bat
start three.bat
```

Answer (score 5):

you better use

```
start cmd /c one.bat
start cmd /c two.bat
start cmd /c three.bat
```

unless you want those windows to remain after bats are finished

Answer (score 3):

To add to this...
If you need to execute them one at a time, instead of all three at once you need to add /wait.. and if you want to run them minimized add /min as follows:

```
start /wait /min cmd /c one.bat
start /wait /min cmd /c two.bat
start /wait /min cmd /c three.bat
exit
```